# Importing Classes and Name Error on specific functions in class

Tags: python

I've tried looking for an answer, but while many posts look similar, they don't quite address the issue I'm having. I have regression class as follows (this is not the full code, only showed the first few lines where it fails):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Lasso, Ridge, ElasticNet
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

class Regression:
    def __init__(self, X, y, testsize):

        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.testsize = testsize
        
        # split training and testing dataset
        self.X_train, self.X_test, self.y_train, self.y_test = train_test_split(self.X, 
            self.y, test_size=self.testsize, random_state=0)
```

I saved this as a separate file called class_reg.py (in the same folder where the rest of my code is). I then import it into Jupyter as follows (experimented with both statements):

```
from class_reg import Regression 
# import class_reg as creg
```

and then tried (both ways):

```
    lin_reg = Regression(X, Y, 0.2)
   # lin_reg = creg.Regression(X, Y, 0.2)
```

only to get:

---

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\LOCAL_~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_19752/1452087210.py in <module>
----> 1 lr = creg.Regression(X, Y, 0.20)
      2 

    ...\Programming\RPython\class_reg.py in __init__(self, X, y, testsize)
         14 class Regression:
         15     def __init__(self, X, y, testsize):
    ---> 16 
         17         self.X = X
         18         self.y = y
    
    NameError: name 'train_test_split' is not defined
```

I'm guessing this might have to do with local variables (I'm not using the correct lingo here).

Not sure what I'm doing wrong....already spent a lot of time researching but no headway. Would appreciate some advice. Thanks!

Update:

Also tried adding "self" in front of train_test_split....no luck:

```
self.X_train, self.X_test, self.y_train, self.y_test = self.train_test_split(self.X, self.y, test_size=self.testsize, random_state=0)
```

Update: 5/2/22

This is what finally worked. Just adding these three lines of code is all it took. I guess I'll know for next time.

```
%matplotlib inline
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Comment: Notice that the error is being indicated on a line that doesn't even mention the supposedly undefined name.  I suspect that you've forgotten to save the file, so Python is running a different version of the code than you think.

Comment: Please post the traceback as code, not an image

Comment: @jasonharper - thanks sir. The file is very much saved. I've hit save multiple times....

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs - done as requested.

Comment: The traceback points to an empty line in the file `class_reg.py`. Something odd is happening. Try using a new python environment.

Comment: @nadapez Tried multiple environments...same issue. Does it run for you? FYI, the code runs fine when I include it in the same python file, only errors out when I import it as a class from a separate file. Also, I'm wondering if I need to define train_test_split as a separate function itself and not as part of the class....??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option:

`Restart your kernel and re-run your cells`

Second Option:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')
```

Then import your file:

```
from class_reg import Regression 


lin_reg = Regression(X, Y, 0.2)
```

Comment: no luck. Still get the same NameError referring to the test_train_split function. I wonder if that function needs to be defined explicitly then? Does it work for you if you call the class from a separate .py file? Appreciate the help!

Comment: @user3654852 I updated the information. Please take a look and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks! this worked. There are some other issues coming up with other functions below. e.g. when I call  pipe , intercept, coef, y_pred = lin_reg.fit_predict(LinearRegression(), StandardScaler()) ; I get " 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'intercept_'". I'll investigate further...but this was a huge help; thanks!!

Comment: Could you please share what option worked for you? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad Bezden. This is what finally worked: I just added the following lines of code - %matplotlib inline
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2 and it started to load up fine. Can't believe I spent hours trying to figure out classes....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file you are showing and the file you are running are the same. I checked multiple times, there does not seem to be an issue with your code.

Comment: Thanks. Both source and target files are in the same folder, and I'm calling the right file name. Still getting the same error. Are you able to import and run it succesfully?